# Prompt user for permissions multiple times in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ios-permissions, react-native-permissions

I am writing an image picker in React-Native. For iOS, I would like the image picker to show the user the option of updating their permissions every time it is toggled open.

```js
import CameraRoll from "@react-native-community/cameraroll"

CameraRoll.getPhotos(params)
```

But the above code will only show the user the permissions prompt once, and every other time it is called per session it will not prompt the user again. I have also tried `react-native-permissions` but ran into the same problem:

```js
import Permissions from "react-native-permissions"

const res = await Permissions.request(UtilsSystem.RN_PERMISSIONS.CAMERA)
```

Is there a way to re-prompt a user for camera permissiosn after they have already been shown the prompt once?

Comment: well, show your toggle, and your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior on purpose. Once a user declined a permission, there is no way to trigger the request again. The best option is to guide the user how to enable internally and link to the device permissions.

If the user accepted the permission there is no need to re-prompt as it is permanent.